# Which (if any) email clients implement the Expires header?

Tags: email

Do any current email clients implement handling of the "Expires" email header (RFC 4021 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.49)?
By handling of, I mean automatic (optional) deleting of expired messages as well as user interface to setting an expiry date on outgoing email.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Outlook (versions Outlook for Office 365, Outlook 2019, Outlook 2016, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2010) allows setting of expiry date on outgoing email.

Microsoft Office Reference: [Set a message expiration date](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-a-message-expiration-date-fcae213f-8d38-4318-a17b-42d83ac209ed)

The Outlook client does not include a way to auto-delete expired messages, but it does display them with <del>strikethrough</del> font modifier.